# Cannot Scroll UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I've got a `UIScrollView` in IB linked to the delegate and with the proper referencing outlet, declared in my header:

`IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;`

And called in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 500)];
}
```

It has the correct size and width in IB, and the default values in the Attributes inspector.

Why can't I scroll it?

**EDIT:** Also, layer wise there is no other view conflicting for a z-index.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is the content size larger than the scrollview's frame? That's the only way it'll scroll.

Comment: Hmmm can you post a screenshot of the IB settings? Weird, as long as the outlet is hooked up properly and you actually are setting the content size to larger than the height or width of the uiscrollview it should work.

Comment: Tada! Sorry I'm dumb... I was setting the size of the ScrollView itself on top of the content. Silly silly me. Beat @nikita to it. 2 mins till accept.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, happens to the best of us! :D

Answer (score 7):

Double-check that you have content size bigger than scroll view size itself. If it will be bigger it will scroll.

Comment: Righto but @mjisrawi beatcha. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

m using Xcode 6/iOS 8+ now with auto-layout turned on, and I had the same problem in the first place, removing auto-layout doesn't work at all, so in order to make scroll view scrollable vertically, I made sure the following:

1. The scroll view content size height MUST be bigger than the screen
   height, this almost goes without saying...
2. The top/bottom/left/right constraint of the scroll view HAS TO BE
   pinned, I did this using storyboard so no code showing up here

If you want to make the scroll view scrollable horizontally, then make sure its content size width is bigger than the screen width, the other rule applies the same.

This worked for me, hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

[enable scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjh88.png)

check "Scolling Enabled" and make sure the content size is larger than the screen height

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: <content height>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the answer to your question was when you asked.

For now, under *AutoLayout*, setting constraints for scroll view just solve your problem.

[image]